# Data transfer between android device and Linux based hardware

Tags: java, android, linux

I want to send and receive data from a Linux based hardware piece to an android device. The hardware device is connected to Hotspot created by android device. Can you please suggest some links or tutorial from where I can get idea how to establish communication between hardware device and the android device to send and receive data through WI-FI .Please Help any sample code or links

Answer (score 0):

There is an enormous amount of ways to do it. The easiest one is running an ftp server on the linux machine and upload the file to it from the Android app via the `FTPClient` class from Apache Commons.
While this is very easy to establish it is very unsecure, and should only be used in your local wifi.